# how can I view the schema of my sqlite database in pycharm?

Tags: sqlite, pycharm

I have sqlite database in a django project and everything works fine.

But seeing django dbshell does not work with sqlite I found pycharm has a database connector/manager but I can't find where I can input sql commands or see the schema.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok found it it is on the far right side of the window there is a "database" tab

In pycharm 5 pro at least

Comment: Not for 2017.3.4

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: For anyone coming across this problem, I fixed it with JetBrains toolbox. Just upgrade PyCharm, using default configurations.

## Detailed Instructions

1. Download [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/), if you don't have it already.
2. If you installed PyCharm **via JetBrains Toolbox**, then skip this step. Otherwise,  *uninstall* PyCharm and then reboot.
3. Launch Jetrbrains Toolbox, and enter your license information.
4. Install / Update PyCharm using the Toolbox.
5. Launch PyCharm using JetBrains Toolbox.
6. If you are prompted to import configuration files from an older version of PyCharm, **do *not* import**. If you need those configurations, then I recommend manually setting them afterward.
7. Open your existing project.
8. Open the Database tool window (`View -> Tool Windows -> Database`)
9. PyCharm should autodetect the Django Sqlite3 database.
10. Click the notification, and it should add a data-source called `Django default`.